# JavaScript header and prototype

Tags: javascript

Why will `a.prototype == b.prototype` evaluate to `true`? What have I misunderstood?

```js
var a=new A();
var b=new B();
function A(){};
function B(){};

console.log (a instanceof A);
console.log(b instanceof A);
console.log(a.prototype== b.prototype);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of `A` and `B`, respectively `a` and `b` don't have a property `prototype`. So when you are checking `a.prototype == b.prototype` you're basically doing `undefined == undefined` (which is `true`).

You can check by simply logging `a.prototype`, it will return `undefined`.

But `A` and `B` do have prototypes and they are different:

```js
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

function A() {};
function B() {};

console.log(A.prototype == B.prototype);
```